# Add cookie or localstorage to my react.js webapplication

Tags: cookies, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im working on my first react.js project and its a recipe-generator.

**My project looks like this:**

View 1: choose a baseingredient

View 2: choose more ingredients

View 3: get a list of recipes that includes some of the ingredients and the baseingredient, click on one recipe.

View 4: choosen recipe will be displayed here :)

Now I would like to add cookies or localstorage to my choosen ingredients to make it possible to reload the page without emptying my ingredients-array.

My problem is that I don't really know how to do this.

**This is how I set my baseingredient :**

```
import React from 'react';
import Actions from '../../../actions/actions';
import BaseIngredientButton from './BaseIngredientButton';

class BaseIngredientItem extends React.Component {

  _OnClick (props) {
    Actions.addItem(this.props.baseIngredient)
    Actions.setBaseIngredient( this.props.baseIngredient )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <BaseIngredientButton isChosen={this.props.isChosen} onClick={ this._OnClick.bind(this)} txt={ this.props.baseIngredient.name } />
    )
  }
}

BaseIngredientItem.propTypes = { 
  baseIngredient: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  isChosen: React.PropTypes.bool
}

export default BaseIngredientItem;
```

Can someone give me some tip how to make this possible?

Comment: Do not use base classes. React prefers composition over inheritance. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

I use [localforage](http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/)
heavily for client side persistence. It auto detects which browser storage mechanisms are available and gives you an unified API across all storage solutions.
Localeforage uses promises so you need to polyfill them for browsers that don't have promise support.

Answer (score 0):

You can set local storage items by calling localStorage.setItem("baseIngredient", "eggs") then retrieve it with localStorage.baseIngredient    http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp